# Is there a simple way to stop Pandas from changing object types?

Tags: pandas

I am new to Pandas and what drives me crazy is that Pandas changes the object type with every copy operation.

Every time I do a df=df or df[x]=df[y] then all int become a float, all columns with only "nan" become a float. That makes it very difficult to properly compare data frame or use the data frames as input for API calls.

Yes, you can tell json.dumps to treat floats as strings and so on, but then the original value "1617" becomes "1617.0" in the df and the same as string(with ".0").

Of course I could change back the object type after every operation, but that is tedious. I thought there must be an easier way.

Comment: The copy operation doesn't change dtypes but you might be performing some operations on the dataframe before that which introduces `NaN`. Since `NaN` itself is treated as a float, the whole column becomes float. Hence, focus on avoiding `NaNs`

Comment: can you create a small, simple example of what you mean? I can't reproduce this problem Empusas

Comment: normal `int` type will be cast to float if there are `NaN` added to the column as @VishnudevKrishnadas mentioned. Use `'Int64'` dtype for nullable integer./